# Python Selenium Webdriver click() function doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a test for a website using Python and Selenium.
Today I've noticed the script misses webdriver.click() function - it doesn't give any errors, but nothing is happened.
Code hasn't been changed for a long time.

I've made a simple test to see if the problem in my code or something in Selenium. I've used one from the old tutorial:

```
url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
path_to_chromedriver_user_data = path.abspath(path.join(__file__, "../../chromedriver/chrome user data"))
path_to_chromedriver = path.abspath(path.join(__file__, "../../chromedriver"))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + path_to_chromedriver_user_data)
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
# options.add_argument('--incognito')
# options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver + '/chromedriver', options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/a")
print(button.text)
button.click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

It correctly finds the element and outputs:

```
Courses
```

But click itself doesn't happen. What may cause the issue?
I've downloaded a recent version of a chromdriver. Selenum module is also up to date.

If launch script in terminal, it also gives the following errors from the chromedriver:

```
[13124:10848:1030/184929.987:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[13124:10848:1030/184935.403:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
```

But I think I saw those errors before and everything worked just fine.

Please help!

AN UPDATE:
I've also updated a google chrome: nothing.
Then I've downgraded: nothing :(

AN UPDATE 2:
I've emptied the user data folder (I have a custom folder for selenium chrome user data) from chrome and cleared all local files.
Then it worked!
Weird issue tho. Still zero idea what caused it.

**I THINK I'VE FOUND A SOLUTION:
looks like this bug is caused by Chrome zoom level. Before my zoom level was 33%. But after deleting cookies and user data it got reset back to 100%. Playing with it i've found if it is below certain amount, webdriver.click() stops working.**

Comment: My guess is that you are clicking too early. Have you tried waiting for clickable on that element and then clicking it? Also that locator is very brittle and with a UI change would end up clicking the wrong element. A better locator would make the script more resilient and also make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thank you! That is an extremely important point!
in a proper application of course should be used `button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[@class = .....")))`.

Moreover, you are 100% correct that this type of path shouldn't be used.

But this is just a simple example that I made for testing. So please don't be too harsh on it.

Problem is not that element can't be found, but the click doesn't happen for some reason.
Please note, that element is being located absolutely fine - I've even add a `print` to double check it.

Comment: SOLVED IT: I've emptied the user data folder (I have a custom folder for selenium chrome user data) from chrome and cleared all local files.
Then it worked!